# Getting sum of all the values of a choice column in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list

I have a choice column with choices as numbers in a list. I want to sum all the values in the column and display it,
Is there any easy way of doing it?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question, please? Where would you want to store the sum of the values? One option in doing it is iterating the choice list and calculating the sum using CSOM and javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we don't get the `sum` option in the `total` section of `modify list`,we can do it by

- Adding a `number column` and filling it using workflow with choice's number
- Then for this `number column` we will be getting the **sum** option in the `total` section of modify list.

And it's done..